# Does $\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x}dx$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, even-and-odd-functions

Does
$\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x}dx$ Converge or diverge?

Is the following a valid proof of convergence?:

\begin{align}
&= \lim_{a\to0+}\left(\int_{-1}^{-a}\frac{1}{x}dx + \int_{a}^1\frac{1}{x}dx\right)\\
&= \lim_{a\to0+}\left([\ln|x|]_{-1}^{-a} + [\ln|x|]_{a}^{1}\right)\\
&= \lim_{a\to0+}(\ln|-a| - \ln|a| + \ln|1|-\ln|-1|)\\
&= \lim_{a\to0+}\left(\ln\left|\frac{-a}{a}\right|\right)\\
&= \ln|-1| = \ln{1} = 0
\end{align}

Thanks.

Comment: You have computed the inetgral in the Cauchy principal value sense. But the function is not Riemann (or Lebesgue) integrable in the ordinary sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Right so this means it is convergent in the Cauchy Principal value sense?

Comment: http://www.pitt.edu/~jwheeler/Principal%20Values.pdf

Comment: No, the integral is never convergent. It is used to extrapolate values of integrals that do not converge and give them values. It's the same as saying $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots = -\frac{1}{12}$: of course, the sum does not converge, but according to similar sums we can give this sum a value by analytic continuation.

Comment: According to the definition of CPV here the intergal does converge in the CPV sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks, that's perfect.